# Mysql2 error while using RSpec fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, fixtures, rake-task

I've added a dependency to both `order` and `order_items` fixtures (which already existed), but I'm receiving the following error every time I run my rspec worker test.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Mysql2::Error: Table 'inventory_test10.order_packages' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `order_packages` /*controller:,action:,line:*/
```

I have an `order` which has many `order_items` and many `order_packages`. `order_items` also belong to `order_packages`. Therefore, I am able to do:

```
order.order_items.each do |oi|
  put oi.order_package.status
end
```

The original issue was that status wasn't recognized for nil class because an `order_packages.yml` fixture was never created. I've tried several rake tasks, but I'm not super familiar with fixtures, migrations, rake tasks, etc and I'm not sure if I accidentally caused the error running multiple taks. Below is a snippet from a blog that warned about running the command multiple times - http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/using-rails-fixtures-to-seed-a-database/:

> rake db:fixtures:load FIXTURES=credit_card_types
>
> A word of warning, if we run this command multiple times, it will seed
> the table multiple times. It’s not idempotent.

Other tasks I ran:

- FIXTURES=orders; rake db:fixtures:load
- rake db:fixtures:dump (didn't work - error)
- rake db:fixtures:drop (didn't work - error)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: did you run the migration in test environment?

Comment: I did. Then I went into the test rails console and didn't find any seeded data at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your test framework should automatically load fixtures at the beginning of the test run, and delete them at the end of the test run. You should not need to load fixtures yourself.

Fixtures load data into tables; they do not alter the database structure. Migrations can alter the database by creating/dropping tables, adding/removing columns, etc. If you are having an issue with a missing table, it is very like a migration problem.

I recommend a review of the [Guide to Testing Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html), and (if you are using RSpec) the [rspec-rails documentation](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-3/docs), which explain these concepts in greater depth.